# Is this a significant case of colinearity? (Plot included)

Tags: multicollinearity

[image]

I wish to include both $x$ (the x-axis) and $y$ (the y-axis) as covariates/predictors in a regression on a separate observation $z$.

They are correlated a bit, as you can see. Will this cause colinearity issues? Or am I ok?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. I think visual inspection might not be enough. What is the correlation between these two variables? Have you considered checking VIF?

Comment: To my addled eyes, this plot looks like Puff the Magic Dragon floating in the sea.  It certainly doesn't look linear!  The correlation coefficient isn't terribly large, either.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your variable Z is continuous and you will fit a linear model. 5 assumptions for linear model are: Linearity on regression coefficients, Existence of error term variance, Homogeneity of error term variance, Independence of the observations, and Normally distributed error term. The normality is needed only when you need statistical tests or/and confidence intervals or/and standard error.

When $X$s have perfect linear relation, we need to drop some of them. Partial linear relation ($R^2$ or $|r|$ < 1) does not invalid any assumptions above. Obviously, your two $X$s are not perfect linear related based your plot. So keep going to fit your linear model.

Comment: I believe the concern in the question is not about *perfect* linearity, but about a sufficient degree of linearity.  Thus, the OP is really asking for an assessment of *how much* linearity might be of concern.  This is an impossible question to answer until they explain how they are using the regression--there may be no concern if the purpose is prediction and great concern if it's to estimate regression coefficients accurately--but you're welcome to make some assumptions about that if you wish.  Therefore your advice to "keep going" seems either inadequately justified or premature.